# How to turn of cache in webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

In my webpack.config I have a cache prop. Does this make sure chunks are not regenerated anytime? I want to generate chunks from scratch every time.

Answer (score 0):

> Cache invalidation can be achieved by including a hash to the
>   filenames.

Assume you have the following configuration:

```
{
  output: {
    ...
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
  },
},
```

Webpack would generate filenames like these based on it:

```
main.d587bbd6e38337f5accd.js
vendor.dc746a5db4ed650296e1.js
```

Learn more about webpack caching:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching

Comment: Ok btw can I put console.logs in the webpack files ?

Comment: @bierhier Yes, just you can place console.log out of the webpack's config object.